# Cant call named function when defining event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

Basically I am trying to pass an object to a function, the object has a named function as one of its parameters as follows:

```
callFunctionOne({
        buttons: [{
            label: 'label',
            action: function e(dialog) {
                dialog.setTitle('Title 1');
            }}]
})

function callFunctionOne(options){

  let buttons = options['buttons'];
  for (let t = 0; t < buttons.length; t++){
     let button = buttons[t];
     $(document).on('click','#'+'amazingID'+button['label'],function(g){
       // Trying to call the function on button click only
       button.action.e();
     });
  }
}
```

So,
This is how I'm trying to write it but its obviously wrong because I get e is not defined as a function error.

What am I doing wrong here, how do I go about passing a function as a parameter and then defining that the function is only called when the button is clicked?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `var`, *especially* with asynchronous code. (it also looks like you have a typo, use either the `t` or `i` variable names, but not both)

Comment: Sorry , yes the i variable name was a typo error which has now been changed.

Comment: Changed var to let however this still does not work?

Comment: Your `callFunctionOne` call's syntax is invalid - you have a `[` but no matching `]`, which will cause a SyntaxError

Comment: Yup , thats what happens when I type code directly into the text box, now sorted. Still getting button.action.e is not a defined function :(